# COMException Exception message: The handle is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070006 (E_HANDLE))

Tags: iis

I deploy a web application in Production Server. In Production we are using Windows Server 2012, IIS 8.5. Deploying the application was successful but I got the error after 2-3 hours or 1 day from deploying the web application.

The exception is given below

```
**Exception information:** 

**Exception type**: COMException

**Exception message:** The handle is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070006 (E_HANDLE)) 

at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)

   at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.ReMapHandlerAndGetHandlerTypeString(HttpContext httpContext, String path, Boolean& handlerExists)

   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()

   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

I've tried the following:

- Stop and Start IIS
- Restart the Window Server
- Gave enough permission in application

Comment: I'm trying to debug an issue with an Umbraco CMS site using a samba share as the file store. 

Whenever a node is created, one of the load balanced IIS servers will throw this error until the application pool is reset. It looks like a file has been destroyed and recreated and one of the IIS servers has a handle to it which is no longer valid.

The issue is new since upgrading to IIS 8.5

Comment: The solution to my problem was to use https://github.com/Shazwazza/UmbracoExamine.TempStorage to configure the examine indexes to be on local storage rather than on the IIS store. When nodes were published, examine created/destroyed various index files and the "other" server in the cluster still had an open handle to the destroyed file.